# Python POST requests returned a 403 error code

Tags: python, python-requests

This is the code I used :

```
import requests as r

url = "https://mullvad.net/fr/account/login"

data = {
    'account_number': '0000000000000000',
}

headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0','referer':'https://www.google.com/search?q=mullvad+vpn&sxsrf=AB5stBifvquhJHyisKh4n0e6ftNcfGP4dg%3A1690514171757&source=hp&ei=-zLDZLOeLJOji-gP9r2vuAc&iflsig=AD69kcEAAAAAZMNBC_3MN5DgYoKyrXKkthBzIfFs3OjA&oq=&gs_lp=Egdnd3Mtd2l6IgAqAggBMgcQIxjqAhgnMgcQIxjqAhgnMgcQIxjqAhgnMgcQIxjqAhgnMgcQIxjqAhgnMgcQIxjqAhgnMgcQIxjqAhgnMgcQIxjqAhgnMgcQIxjqAhgnMgcQIxjqAhgnSPMnUABYAHABeACQAQCYAQCgAQCqAQC4AQHIAQCoAgo&sclient=gws-wiz'}


response = r.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)
```

And what it returned in console :

```
403
```

I'm trying to send an account number on the website and it has this shape because of the multipart form-data.

Comment: HTTP 403 means "Forbidden" so I'd assume you need to authenticate to the server.

Comment: Yeah but I absolutely have no idea on what to do so I'm waiting for an answer, but thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you check the response message on the request, you will see it is actually

> Cross-site POST form submissions are forbidden

To get around this we need to define the origin in the headers of our request.

For example:

```
import requests

url = "https://mullvad.net/fr/account/login"

payload = 'account_number=0000000000000000'
headers = {
  'Origin': 'https://mullvad.net',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```